# Adjusting The Frequency of X Axis Labels in WPF Charting Toolkit

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts, toolkit

I am confounded by the XAML markup in general and especially for the chart toolkit and would greatly appreciate help sorting it out. I have successfully created a chart with the X axis showing timeline and Y axis showing a value using XAML below:

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,12,0,0" Name="chart1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="521" Width="826">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis IntervalType ="Hours" Interval="1">
                <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>                                   
                                <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:H}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>                       
            </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis>
          </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries x:Name="LineSeries1" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="violet"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

In the code-behind I populate a dictiory declared as  `Dictionary<TimeSpan, float> Dict = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, float>();` with values every minute for 2 hours (60 values) and set the datacontext for `lineseries1` to the dictionary as such:  `LineSeries1.DataContext = Dict.`

The graph draws beautifully, However as apparent from my futile attempt in the XAML. I need the X label and tick marks to show up only once per hour and not once per minute and I need it to show only hours and not minutes and seconds. My XAML code above for adjusting the interval and formatting of the label does not work. I would appreciate any pointer to steer me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Kalory

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you planned if you add orientation to your DateTimeAxis, like this:

`<chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis Orientation="X" IntervalType ="Hours" Interval="1">`

I don't know why it makes difference, but it seem it does...